# IMPORTRANGE cannot be used along with normal filtering system

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, reporting, dashboard

I have a website in English that I just translated in multiple languages.
For my English website, I have a dashboard where I track the performance of all my URLs on a monthly basis. I update this list when a new article is being published. Now, every time a new articles is published in English, it will be automatically translated in other languages and a new URL will be added to my website.

**I'm trying to find a way to mirror my English report for all the other languages without having to maintain the URLs list the same way I do with English.**

I thought using an IMPORTRANGE from my English master file where I will grab the list of URLs would be the best solution. However, by doing this, I won't be able to use the filter in my other dashboards.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

I've made a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q-nEXdKVEKYxUSpdVV6Dvh-UKo3k5lXOnN1dhEs2-Lk/edit#gid=787339805) to quickly show my issue.

Comment: What is the part that doesn't work? I've tried modifying the selected values of Sales and they're correctly filtered

Comment: Hi @Martín if you look at the list of URLs in column A, it does not change while the value in column B does (typically I'm using sort Z to A / A to Z)

Comment: I've just let Sales with only number 5 and I'm seeing the two corresponding values of URLs. What I think your issue is is that you're trying to sort the data of IMPORTRANGE and your manual input of sales. Am I right?

Comment: @Martín Sorry If I'm not wording my issue correctly. Basically if you play with Sort A -> Z and Z -> A function, you will see that the values change order but not URL. For instance, www.mycompany.com/blog/Title1 has 20 for Z -> A. But the number is 5 when you sort Z -> Z. I believe IMPORTANGE does not work with this kind of filters

Comment: Could the sorting in your imported range be changed in your source sheet? I understand you're going to update the links, but the main issue is if the original distribution will remain

Comment: @Martín The list of URLs in the original sheet also has a similar filter system. But even though it will remain consistent, the filter won't be working with IMPORTRANGE.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an imported range and manually input data, you won't be able to "join" them for the sorting part inside the filter. I was asking you if source data would remain in the same order, because if it does (meaning your new data will be "aligned" row by row with your manually input sales), you can sort and filter the range via formula in another column:

```
=SORT(A2:B,2,0)
```

[image]

With some filter:

```
=SORT(FILTER(A2:B,B2:B>=10),2,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Martín. Unfortunately, the source data won't remain in the same order. I actually just realized that the "filter view" could solve my issue.

Comment: You will have the same issue then with Filter View if you can't have your data alligned. If you can, use filter view with your raw data so it remains steady. Then you can use a second filter view in this spreadsheet. But remember you won't have a solution if your original data "moves" in your source sheet

Comment: I've tried with the filter view. It does actually work as long as the formulas are split by individual cell (all the ARRAYFORMULAS, MAP/LAMBDA, will mess up with the filters). I guess it's not the cleanest way but it does the job. Thanks again for your help.